# How to shorten this Python print expression?

Tags: python, list, printf

I have following code dealing with printing the output of two lists as string, eventually if the list is empty it should print "EMPTY".
It works, but I would like make it somehow shorter.

```
new = [0,1,3]
old = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
'to: %s from: %s' % (','.join(map(str,new if len(new) > 0 else ["EMPTY"])),','.join(map(str,old if len(old) > 0 else ["EMPTY"])))
#'to: 0,1,3 from: 0,1,2,3,4,5'
```

Any suggestion will be apriciated.

Assumptions:

- I have to do it without `.format`

---

UPDATE:

So far I managed to do it this way:

```
'to: %s from: %s' % tuple(','.join(map(str,i if i else ["EMPTY"])) for i in (new, old))
```

Comment: btw a note beside If any time you couldn't shorten a line in your code, wrap them in multiple lines at `,`.

Comment: this was not only about length of characters but also about good coding practice without stupid repetitions. DRY! DRY!

Comment: Yes that I understand. Answers to your question provides some good tricks those are helpful to me as well. Good luck (y) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using `print` (so you can print a list) or do you need to generate the string?

```
>>> print "to:", new or "EMPTY" , "from:" , old or "EMPTY"
to: [1, 2, 3] from: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> new = []
>>> print "to:", new or "EMPTY" , "from:" , old or "EMPTY"
to: EMPTY from: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: If you don't want the brackets, you can use `str(new)[1:-1]` instead of `new`

Comment: It is maybe not my favourite answer, but I accept it as very easy and straightforward way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To make this readable I'd just factor out the formatting into a function:

```
def fmt(l):
   return ','.join(map(str, l)) if l else 'EMPTY'

print 'to: %s from: %s' % (fmt(new), fmt(old))
```

Comment: can we further do `print 'to: %s from: %s' % map(fmt, (new, old))` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan no, `%` won't unpack the `map` - you could do it with `.format(*map(...))`, though

Comment: @jonrsharpe, NPE you are correct present form is better than `.format(*map(...))` thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
pretty = lambda a: ','.join(map(str, a)) or 'EMPTY'
'to: %s from: %s' % (pretty(old), pretty(new))
```

Comment: you mixed order of old and new ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
"to: {0} from: {1}".format(str(new)[1:-1] if new else "EMPTY", 
                           str(old)[1:-1] if old else "EMPTY")
```

All empty containers, including `[]`, evaluate `False`, so you don't need to explicitly check the `len()`. `str()` will convert the list to a string (e.g. `"[1, 2, 3]"`) then the slice `[1:-1]` takes all but the first character (`'['`) and the last (`']'`).

You can do the same thing with `%`, but it is deprecated:

```
"to: %s from: %s" % (str(new)[1:-1] if new else "EMPTY", 
                     str(old)[1:-1] if old else "EMPTY")
```

**Note**: this uses Python's default `list` display, which puts spaces after the commas. If you really can't live with that, you could do:

```
"to: %s from: %s" % (str(new)[1:-1].replace(" ", "") if new else "EMPTY", 
                     str(old)[1:-1].replace(" ", "") if old else "EMPTY")
```

Comment: This will join with `, ` instead of `,`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah will prevent migrating to 3.x unfortunately.

Comment: @arshajii true, but I wasn't sure if that was a deal-breaker - it's the default `list` display. I will add a comment to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, you can drop the `len()` calls on both of them, though honestly I'd probably just refactor.

```
new = [0,1,3] or ["EMPTY"]
old = [0,1,3] or ["EMPTY"]
print "to: %s from: %s" % (','.join(map(str,new)), ','.join(map(str,old)))
```

Comment: i would like to stay inline (in one line)